# Running multiple node.js projects on single linux server

Tags: node.js, linux, server, discord.js

So I have 2 chat bots, one for Twitch and one for Discord, that I want to move from my PC to my linux based server so that they are just running all the time for convenience. Is there any way to do this?

Obviously I can run each bot by themselves on the server but I can't figure out if and how to do so.

Comment: It's not clear what's stopping you.

Comment: I assume you're having difficulty because you're running Node in the foreground and actually want to run it in the background. You can add an ampersand to the end of a command in most *nix shells to run it in the background. That way you can spawn one after another without having to exit the fist. e.g. `node app.js &`. That said, I agree with @zmehall that you should use `pm2` to manage your processes. It has many configurable options for logging, restarting, starting on reboot, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a package like `pm2` to run node apps in the background.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2

```
sudo npm install pm2 -g

pm2 start your-app.js
```

You can use pm2 to start both apps, and they'll continue to run after you close the shell.